# Submitting a Form now I have added a MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, master-pages

I see all kinds of questions all over Google about using Javascript for these things, mainly revolving around the problems of ASP.NET changing the IDs of everthing, but this is NOT my problem.

I have a very simple form, contained within a content page, it contains these form elements:

```
<asp:TextBox id="coName" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox id="pass" TextMode="password" runat="server" />
<asp:Button id="enterAdmin" text="Enter" runat="server" clientidmode="static"/>
```

These are wrapped in the master page form.

My button handling code is:

```
Sub submit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles enterAdmin.Click
    Dim company = coName.Text
    Dim pwd = pass.Text
 '// DO MORE STUFF
End Sub
```

All works perfectly when using this page as a standalone page, but when I add a masterpage to it I get two problems

Firstly, the button click event is not triggered. This, I have overcome, by some Googling and found that adding this line:

```
    Me.RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent(enterAdmin)
```

Fixes the problem of the click event

But, my second problem: I cannot get the field values coming through

```
coName.Text
pass.Text
```

Are both coming through as empty strings.

What am I missing?

Comment: Those values should be available in your pages codebehind, but not if you are trying to reach them in your masterpages codebehind.

Comment: I am trying to use them in the Page. They're just empty though.

Comment: I cannot get this to work, but using `Request.Form("coName")` etc, does work. I'll just stick to that.

Comment: But it sounds like a workaround? Can we see the markup please?